# 連続して cat を実行した結果を、カンマ区切りの CSV で保存したい（ adb shell ）

Tags: android, bash, sh, adb

PC の `bash` から `adb shell` に入り、連続して `cat` を実行した結果を、カンマ区切りの CSV で PC へと保存したいです。

列1 に項目名を、列2 に `cat` した結果を保存する方法をご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

スクリプト:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -v              
echo "項目1"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack     >> hogelist.txt
echo "項目2"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max     >> hogelist.txt
echo "項目3"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem     >> hogelist.txt
```

現在の出力結果 ( `hogelist.txt` )

```
項目1
1
項目2
163840
項目3
4098    46284   1094304
```

出力したい結果 ( `hogelist.csv` )

```
項目1,1
項目2,163840
項目3,4098    46284   1094304
```

Comment: 今回の質問に限りませんが、質問に具体性が足りません。失敗した結果だけでなく、期待する結果も示してください。入力(/hoge? の内容)も示してください。そのほうが期待する回答を得られやすくなりますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘に沿って質問を編集してみました。

Comment: 補足：hogelist.csvをエクセルで開こうとすると文字化けしたため、下記の行を最後に追加しました。
nkf -s --overwrite hogelist.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

多くの OS の `sh` (bash, zsh も含む) の組込みコマンド `echo` は、`-n` オプションで改行を抑制できます。

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "項目1,"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack     >> hogelist.txt
echo -n "項目2,"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max     >> hogelist.txt
echo -n "項目3,"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem /hoge3     >> hogelist.txt
```

しかし、Solaris など SYSV 系の OS の `sh` の `echo` では `-n` オプションはサポートしていません。代わりに、出力したい文字列の最後に `\c` を付与します。

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "項目1,\c"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack     >> hogelist.txt
echo "項目2,\c"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max     >> hogelist.txt
echo "項目3,\c"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem /hoge3     >> hogelist.txt
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。 ,\cの付与をしている下のパターンで解決いたしました。

Answer (score 3):

それでは以下の様になります。

```
$ awk 'NR%2{printf("%s,", $0)} !(NR%2)' hogelist.txt
```

# もっとも、元のシェルスクリプトだけで最終結果を出力する方が良いかと思いますが。

追記:

bash　ということで、元のシェルスクリプトを以下の様にすることもできるでしょう。

```
#/usr/bin/bash

declare -a input
input=(
  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack
  /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem
)

declare -i i=0
for f in ${input[@]}
do
  printf "項目%d, %s\n" $((i+1)) "$(adb shell cat ${input[$i]})"
  : $((i++))
done
```

ただ、adb shell を使った場合を試していないので、その場合は期待する結果を得られないかもしれません。

追記２:

ご存じの方も多いでしょうが、bash には `printf` という**ビルトインコマンド**が存在します。

```
$ type printf
printf is a shell builtin
```

`/usr/bin/printf` コマンドに対して、いくつかの書式指定文字列が追加されています。

```
$ help printf
      :
%b expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
%q quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
```

これらは、状況によっては便利なこともあります。ご参考までにどうぞ。

Answer (score 2):

`echo -n` だけでも行ける気がしました。

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -v              

echo -n "項目1,"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack     >> hogelist.txt
echo -n "項目2,"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max     >> hogelist.txt
echo -n "項目3,"  >> hogelist.txt
adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem /hoge3     >> hogelist.txt
```

*Output*:

```bash
$ cat hogelist.txt
項目1,1
項目2,163840
項目3,4098    46284   1094304
```

*man*: `LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 man echo`

> 名前
>          echo - 1 行のテキストを表示する
>   ...
>
> 説明
>          STRING を標準出力に出力する
>
> ```
>    -n     最後に改行を出力しない
> ```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
改行しないオプションをつけて、echoする文字列に,を含めるのですね。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっと質問の意図を正しく読み取れているか不安ですが、こういうことでしょうか?

```
$ cat a
koumoku1
koumoku2
koumoku3
$ cat b
111
222
333
$ paste -d',' a b
koumoku1,111
koumoku2,222
koumoku3,333
```

Comment: 当初の質問が曖昧で大変申し訳ございませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

今 adb の環境が手元にないので分かりませんが、コマンド置換では出来ないでしょか？

```
adb shell echo 項目1,`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack` >> hogelist.txt
adb shell echo 項目2,`cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max` >> hogelist.txt
adb shell echo 項目3,`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem` >> hogelist.txt
```

**追記**

```
adb shell sh -c "echo 項目1,`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack` >> hogelist.txt"
adb shell sh -c "echo 項目2,`cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max` >> hogelist.txt"
adb shell sh -c "echo 項目3,`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem` >> hogelist.txt"
```

**さらに追記**

```
adb shell sh -c "echo 項目1,`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack`" >> hogelist.txt
adb shell sh -c "echo 項目2,`cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max`" >> hogelist.txt
adb shell sh -c "echo 項目3,`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem`" >> hogelist.txt
```

Comment: 下記のエラーが返ってきました。
cat: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack: No such file or directory
cat: /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max: No such file or directory
cat: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem: No such file or directory

Comment: 追記の方法で行けないでしょか？adb を起動したホストシェルが `` を先に読んでしまった様です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
adb shell上で>>で保存しようとすると、Android端末内にログを保存しようとしてしまうようで、/system/bin/sh: can't create  hogelist.txt: Read-only file systemというエラーが返ってきております。

Comment: あ、外に保存したいのですね。すみません。あとで追記します。

Comment: いずれもバッククォート内のコマンドラインは adb を起動したシェルにより実行されてしまいます。
`adb shell sh -c 'echo 項目1,`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack`' >> hogelist.txt` でないかと。

Comment: すみません。検証してないのがバレバレですね！fumiyasさんの言うとおりシングルクォートでお願いします！